# How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError while running a servlet on Bluemix?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, ibm-cloud

This is the error that's showing up when I'm trying to run a servlet.
This program runs perfectly as a java application.I am deploying my servlet on Bluemix.

Edit: I'm trying to convert a java application to a servlet which can be deployed on bluemix. My application doesn't have a GUI. It interacts with the user through the console(command line).I'm trying to follow the advice given here:[Convert java application to jsp/servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495634/convert-java-application-to-jsp-servlet)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdfparser/PDFParser
at test.FirstParse.ToText(FirstParse.java:39)
at test.Test.doGet(Test.java:87)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
```

at [internal classes]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Wild guess: The container running your servlet can't find the class `PDFParser`.  But because you have not given us any information, this is as much help as we can give you.

Comment: What more details could I give you? I'm sorry my question isn't descriptive enough. Should I post my code??

Comment: What do you  mean by "runs perfectly as a java application" ?  The structure of a pure Java application and web application are substantially different.

Comment: The application server Bluemix runs your web application "on your behalf": a web application is not usually a Java standalone application (e.g. a *jar*). The application server (web application container) needs to know where to find the PDFParser class: you have to add that class (library) in its classpath in some way.

Comment: I wrote a java application. I'm now trying to convert that java application to a servlet following the advice given in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495634/convert-java-application-to-jsp-servlet.

Comment: @medveshonok117: I have added the project containing the PDFParser class to the "dynamic web project" which is running on Bluemix. What else can I do to add to it's classpath?

Comment: I am not familiar with Bluemix but with others (e.g. JBoss). While you deploy a web app and you want to include a library there are two possibilities: you may include your library (*jar*) in your web app deployment file (e.g. *war* or *ear*) or in your web server library path (e.g. *${SOMEWHERE}/lib* directory) and make it as *provided* for all the web applications you run within the same web server. Which approach to choose depends on how many apps may need that library: if many it may be a good choice to share that library with all the app and put it into the web server *lib* directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [Apache pdfbox jar](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) file to WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I did that. The error is still the same. Any other suggestions?